# I want to use Tensorflow C++ API, but after I build Tensorflow from source, how should I link libraries in Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, tensorflow

I downloaded the source code of tensorflow from github, then I configured it and run `bazel build //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so`. Then how should I link the header files or flags of it. Then I can use Xcode to run my tensorflow code and don't need to use Bazel every time to run my code?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have already found a solution but if not, maybe this will help.

I recently used the information in this article:

http://tuatini.me/building-tensorflow-as-a-standalone-project/

in order to get all the correct pre-requisite modules, produce the required TensorFlow library files and gather together the header files needed to be able to compile Qt C++ project written against the TensorFlow C++ API - no need use Bazel as part of build process for my Qt project and my Qt project source code is completely separate from the TensorFlow source code structure.

If you follow the article and still have an issue with a missing nsync header file, search the comments at the bottom of the page for where to copy the nsync header files from.